# Leaves but no roots

Tags: leaves

My bougainvillea cuttings have leaves but no roots - none. Is that normal? I put the cuttings in soil two weeks ago.  How long for roots ? Will they ever root ?

Answer (score 1):

It can take months for some plant to take root.  Just keep the soil moist and give it some warmth.  Bougainvillea thrive in a warm environment.  The roots are more likely to root if the soil is warm.  I would keep the soil at 23-26°c (75-78°f).  This is more like their natural growing environment.  Some cutting can be stubborn especially slower when the plant is in the semi-dormant state.  I am not sure where you are located, but if it is winter that will make it even slower to root.  That does not mean it will not root during the winter.  It will, as long as the soil is warm enough.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I took bougainvillea cuttings ("Mrs Butts"). They had roots after about 3 months, and about a quarter survived eventually. I put a plastic bag over the pot to increase humidity. This was done in spring.

Comment: I put the cuttings with leaves but no roots in the ground outside (Southern Florida). The leaves shriveled right away.